# How to fix error: expected expression before ‘EvidenceType’ in C program

Tags: c, struct

I am trying to create a C program using structs.

I have created a struct as follows:

```
typedef struct {    
  int   id;
  char  room[MAX_STR];
  char  device[MAX_STR];
  float value;
  int   timestamp;
} EvidenceType;
```

I have created a method that initializes the fields of the struct. I have created a `printEvidence()` method as shown below to print out the above struct.

```
void printEvidence(EvidenceType*){

    char* thermal_string;
    char* sound_string;
    char* emf_string;
    
    int no_of_hours = floor(EvidenceType->timestamp / 3600);
    int no_of_minutes = floor((EvidenceType->timestamp % 3600) / 60);
    int no_of_seconds = EvidenceType->timestamp - (no_of_hours * 3600);
    no_of_seconds = no_of_seconds - (no_of_minutes * 60);
    
    printf("%4s |%25s |%10s |%16s |%10s\n", "ID", "Room", "Device", "Value", "Timestamp");
    
    if(strcmp(EvidenceType->device, "EMF") == 0){
    
        if(EvidenceType->value > 4.0){
        
            emf_string = "(HIGH)";
        }
        else{
        
            emf_string = "";
        }
        printf("%-4d |%25s |%10s |%7.1f%10s |%2d:%2d:%2d\n", EvidenceType->id, EvidenceType->room, EvidenceType->device, EvidenceType->value, emf_string, no_of_hours, no_of_minutes, no_of_seconds);
    }
    else if(strcmp(EvidenceType->device, "THERMAL") == 0){
    
        if(EvidenceType->value < 0.0){
        
            thermal_string = "(COLD)";
        }
        else{
        
            thermal_string = "";
        }
        printf("%-4d |%25s |%10s |%7.2f%10s |%2d:%2d:%2d\n", EvidenceType->id, EvidenceType->room, EvidenceType->device, EvidenceType->value, thermal_string, no_of_hours, no_of_minutes, no_of_seconds);
    }
    else{
    
        if(EvidenceType->value < 35.0){
        
            sound_string = "(WHISPER)";
        }
        else if(EvidenceType->value > 70.0){
        
            sound_string = "(SCREAM)";
        }
        else{
        
            sound_string = "";
        }
        printf("%-4d |%25s |%10s |%7.1f%10s |%2d:%2d:%2d\n", EvidenceType->id, EvidenceType->room, EvidenceType->device, EvidenceType->value, sound_string, no_of_hours, no_of_minutes, no_of_seconds);
    }
}
```

In my main function, I am calling the `printEvidence()` function as follows:

```
EvidenceType a;
printEvidence(&a);
```

When I compile my program, I get the following error:

In function ‘printEvidence’:
error: expected expression before ‘EvidenceType’
int no_of_hours = floor(EvidenceType->timestamp / 3600);

How do I fix this error?

Comment: You need to give the parameter a name and use that name in the function: `void printEvidence(EvidenceType* e){`, and `if (e->value > 4.0){`, etc

Comment: Also, in `main`, the var `a` is not initialized and will contain unknown values. And, there's no need to call `floor` when doing integer division.

Comment: Unfortunately there is a restriction due to which I can't modify the signature of the function and hence I can't add the parameter name. Is there a way I can do it inside the body of the function?

Comment: There are many errors: `EvidenceType` is the type, not a variable. You haven't provided a variable name in function. It would be OK as a prototype, but not as the definition. Think about it: suppose the function takes *two* arguments of the same type... the compiler can't distinguish them by using the type as in `EvidenceType->timestamp`.

Comment: I have created a function that initializes var a before it's printed

Answer (score 1):

In your function definition:

```
void printEvidence(EvidenceType*){
```

You specify the type of the parameter, but you don't specify the name.  While doing so is fine in a function declaration, a definition must include the names of the parameters so that the parameters may be referenced in side of the function.

So change the definition to give the parameter a name, then use that name through the function.

```
void printEvidence(EvidenceType *evedence){
    ...
    int no_of_hours = floor(evedence->timestamp / 3600);
    ...
```

Comment: I am not allowed to change the function signature and hence I can't add the parameter. Is there a way I can do it inside the body of the function?

Comment: @GirlyGirl You're not changing the function signature or adding a parameter.  It will still take a single argument of type `EvidenceType *` and return nothing.  You're just giving the parameter a name.

Comment: @GirlyGirl The signature of a function consists of the number and types of the parameters and the return type.  *That's* the part you can't change.  The *names* of the parameters are not part of the signature.